# Working with ratios - how to get math correct for this question?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, ratio, local-time

On TVTropes, Webcomic Time ([link](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WebcomicTime)) is when real-world time does not reflect the passage of time in the comic, basically, real-time and time in the comic book are asynchronous.

On the link above, it said that one webcomic had time running at a $12\colon1$ ratio of time, so 1 month in the webcomic is about a year in real life.

I tried this calculation:

$$12 + 1 = 13$$

to find out the parts.

How would I find out what $3$ months in the webcomic is equivalent to, in real life, or even for $18$ months - what would be the correct calculations?

I would appreciate any help. I've been learning about ratios recently, and want to ensure I get the calculations 'right'.

Answer (score 0):

Your concept is not so accurate for this scenario. What they meant is that
$$\frac{\text{a unit time in webcomic}}{\text{a unit time in real life}}=\frac{12}{1}\text{.}$$

This means that you simply have to multiply the time in webcomic by $12$ to get an equivalent time in real life.